# CSS Displaying Different In Explorer & Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari, explorer

I am working on a menu in CSS (for a site done with jquery as well) that is supposed to display a blue gradient across all the menu headings and only change to gray when it is moused over.  Instead only the heading for the current page shows up with the gradient in both internet explorer and safari, the other headings are white.  But it appears fine in Chrome.

I have included the CSS involved below.  If anyone could provide me with some tips on what to do to fix this problem I would really appreciate it.  Thanks for your time!

```
.navigation {
width:100%;
height:50px;
float:left;
margin-top:2px;
}
.ddsmoothmenu{
float:left;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul{
z-index:999;
margin:0;
list-style-type:none;
float:left;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li{
position:relative;
display:inline;
float:left;
}
.ddsmoothmenu>ul>li:first-child{
padding-left:0px;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li a{
display:block;
height:36px;
padding:14px 20px 0px 20px;
color:#b3b3b3;
text-decoration:none;
font-size:14px;
font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
text-transform:uppercase;
text-shadow:1px 1px #000;
}
* html .ddsmoothmenu ul li a{
display:inline-block;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li a.selected {

}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li a:link, .ddsmoothmenu ul li a:visited{
color:#b3b3b3;
}
.ddsmoothmenu > ul > li > a:hover, 
.ddsmoothmenu > ul > li.current-menu-item > a {
background-image:url(../images/navi-bg.png);
color:#FFF;
}
.ddsmoothmenu > ul > li > a:hover, 
.ddsmoothmenu > ul > li.current-menu-item > a,
.ddsmoothmenu > ul > li > a.selected {
color:#FFF;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul{
position:absolute;
left:0;
display:none;
visibility:hidden;
margin:0px 0px 0px 0px;
padding:0px 0px 5px 0px;
background:#262626;
border:#2f2f2f solid 1px;
width:200px;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li{
display:list-item;
float:left;
padding:0px 5px;
margin:0px;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li:first-child{
padding-top:5px;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li.last{
padding-bottom:5px;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li ul{
top:0;
margin:0px 0px 0px -15px;
width:191px !important;
background:#393939;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a{
width:165px;
height:24px;
padding:6px 5px 0px 10px;
margin:0;
font-size:13px;
border-radius:2px;
border:none;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a.selected{
background-image:none;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a:hover, .ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li a.selected{
background:none !important;
color:#fff;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li ul li a{
color:#fff !important;
}
.ddsmoothmenu ul li ul li ul li a:hover{
color:#fff !important;
}
* html .ddsmoothmenu{
height: 1%;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

For starter, please provide the IE and Safari version so that we can assist you further.

The border-radius definitely not supported by IE 8 and prior. Even if you are using IE9 and IE10, the behavior could be different with Chrome. The other suspects could be the float and position.

For IE, you could look at [CSS PIE](http://css3pie.com/) for better support on IE.

Comment: Thank you for your response.  The IE version was 10 and Safari 5.1.7.  Thanks for the site recommendation I will check that out too.